# Aplicação C# Windows Forms Com lentidão em certas máquinas

Tags: c#, winforms

Boa tarde, realizei a migração de uma aplicação que rodava em um windows ce para desktop, a Aplicação utiliza o Sql Server Compact 4.0. e roda muito bem no ambiente de desenvolvimento, testei em outras máquinas de desenvolvimento e todas rodam bem, telas abrem normal e sem lentidão, porém em outros computadores, ocorre lentidão na maioria das rotinas, pude perceber que geralmente são nas rotinas onde tem interação com o banco de dados. telas que abrem em 1segundo nas máquinas de desenvolvimento, levam de 5 a 8 em outras.

***- Em todas as máquinas foram instaladas o Sqlce Server Compact 4.0 (SSCERuntime_x64-PTB)***

***- Todas as máquinas que realizei o teste tem processadores 64bits.***

***- Aplicação foi compilada em Release.***

***- O banco está na mesma pasta da aplicação, as consultas que são feitas nele nas máquinas que apresentam lentidão, funcionam, porém demandam muito mais tempo do que nas máquinas de desenvolvimento***

Não é problema de lentidão isolado em uma máquina, ou por falta de processamento, pois a aplicação é bastante simples, roda com poucas tabelas, testei em mais de 1 servidor e apresentaram a lentidão.

Acredito ser algo que falta instalar nas máquinas, porém não identifiquei o que. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Possível causa/solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354917/sql-server-ce-extremely-slow-on-some-computers

Comment: achei isso a alguns minutos atrás e estou verificando. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom dia a todos, encontrei a solução do problema.

A Lentidão ocorre quando se usa assembly .NET 1.1 ou 2.0 que são **authenticode-signed** . A demora é devido ao .NET fazer esta verificação e não conseguir baixar o CLR com as assinaturas.

Tudo está muito bem explicado no link abaixo:

> http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/18E25101F0839C6286256F960061B282

Utilizei a primeira opção paleativa, de desmarcar a opção no Internet Option, funcionou perfeitamente, no post tem uma segunda solução para ser feita no Aplicativo, irei verificala.

Muito obrigado a todos.